# How to create an arbitrary mapping in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a React app where I want to [display lunar phases](https://github.com/dhappy/clock). To that end I tried to create an empty array and then `map` it appropriately:

```
import React from 'react'

export const MoonPhase = (props) => {
  let start = new Date(props.start)
  let end = new Date(props.end)

  let delta = (end.getTime() - start.getTime()) / 1000
  let quarters = new Array(Math.floor(
    // Each lunar month is 2.55ᴇ6s.
    (delta / (2.55 * Math.pow(10, 6))) * 4
  ))

  return (
    <div className='phases'>
      {quarters.map((_, i) => {
        switch(i % 4) {
          case 0: return <span></span>
          case 1: return <span></span>
          case 2: return <span></span>
          case 3: return <span></span>
        }
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

This doesn't produce anything, but if I change `quarters` to `[1,2,3,4,5]` I get output.

How should I approach this?

Comment: Easiest fix is to add `.fill()` after `new Array(...)`, but it would be better to do `Array.from({ length: ... }, (_, i) => { ... })` instead of using `new Array()` and `.map()`.

Comment: If I remember correctly, `.map` skips over “holes” and `new Array(n)` basically creates an array with `n` holes.